# Need to retrieve Maximum and Minimum Values from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have the below 2 tables

Table Name: Port

```
City        Code
------------------
City A      001
City B      002
City C      003
City D      004
City E      005
City F      006
City G      007
```

Table Name: Shipments

```
Code        Shipments
------------------
001         5
001         4
002         2
003         4
003         3
003         4
004         1
005         1
006         1
007         2
```

I want to get the list of Cities where maximum shipments take place.

Answer:

```
City        Total Shipments
------------------------
City C      11
City D      1
City E      1
City F      1
```

Can someone help me with the SQL query for this.

Comment: Interesting reading for you: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Is this homework?

Comment: Why is this the answer? :S What's the logic ?

Comment: I think your answer is not correct

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.city as City, sum(s.shipments) as Shipments
from 
   port c  
inner join 
    shipments s on s.code = c.code     
group by c.code
order by sum(s.shipments) asc;
```

Check this out and let me know.

Comment: I need to get the city with the maximum shipment and also the cities with minimum shipments within the same Query..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Common Table Expression` (CTE) to first aggregate the shipments for each City. The `min` and `max` records can then be returned as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (   SELECT P.city AS City, 
                    SUM(S.shipments) AS TotalShipments
                FROM Port P  
                INNER JOIN Shipments S ON S.code = P.code     
                GROUP BY P.city )
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE c.TotalShipments IN ( SELECT MAX(c2.TotalShipments) RequiredTotalShipments
                            FROM cte c2
                            UNION
                            SELECT MIN(c3.TotalShipments)
                            FROM cte c3 )
```

Comment: Has this helped Pankaj?